# types of Trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

So I know there are different trig identities such as Double‐Angle and Half‐Angle Identities, but how would I answer a question with a fraction identity? For example

> Given that $\cos (x) = 0.8$, what is $\tan\left(\dfrac32x\right)$?

Comment: $\tan(3x/2)=\tan(x+x/2)$

Comment: There are formulas for half-integers, not for larger denominators.

Comment: You question smells like a homework.

Comment: no, im just trying to understand how it works, the answer should be 1.44.                 i tried adding tan x to tan x/2, but i got 1.66 so i guess im making a mistake, but thanks everybody!

Comment: @smithcarlson That will not work as it's not true that $\tan(x+y) = \tan(x) + \tan(y)$.  Same goes for other trig functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\tan\tfrac{x}{2}$ so$$0.8=\tfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\implies t=\pm\tfrac13\implies\tan x=\tfrac{2t}{1-t^2}=\pm\tfrac34,\,\tan\tfrac{3x}{2}=\pm\tfrac{\frac13+\frac34}{1-\frac13\frac34}=\pm\tfrac{13}{9}\approx\pm1.44.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you want func(3x/2), where [func] is some combination of cosine and sine.  You are given cosine x which means that you can derive sine x.  Then, you can derive cos 3x and sine 3x.  Then you can apply half angle formulas to your [func] 3x derivations.

Also, **metacheating** is helpful here:  the problem is well defined (except that you don't know whether sine x is positive or negative).  Therefore, the problem must **somehow** be solvable, which suggests that the strategy in the above paragraph **will work.**

$\underline{\text{addendum}}$ 
I am adding this addendum to respond to the OP's reaction.

First of all, for a demonstration that 
$\;\sin(a + b) = \sin \,a \cos \,b + \cos \,a \sin \,b,\;$ see the Angle sum identities section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities.

Secondly, the OP's comment which I am reacting to, indicates an alternative but perfectly valid approach.  Instead of deriving [func] 3x (et al), the OP is apparently deriving [func] x/2, and using the angle sum identities to compute [func] (x + x/2).

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer!  just one more question, i have derived sinx and sinx/2 aswell as cosx/2 , my question is how is  sin (x+x/2) equal to  = sinx cosx/2 + cosx sinx/2  is there a formula im missing? im really sorry for the basic questions and i really do appreciate your help.  thank you!

Comment: @smithcarlson I added an addendum to my answer in response.